# geometry question on incenters

Tags: geometry

Let D, E, F be the points of contact of the incircle of an acute-angled triangle ABC with BC, CA, AB respectively. Let $I_{1}, I_{2}, I_{3}$ be the incentres of the triangles AFE, BDF, CED, respectively. How do I prove that the lines $I_{1}D, I_{2}E, I_{3}F$ are concurrent.

Comment: Hint: show that $I_1,I_2,I_3$ lie on the incircle of $ABC$ with $EI_1=I_1F$, $FI_2=I_2D$, $DI_3=I_3E$.

Comment: They intersect in the [first mid-arc point](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Mid-ArcPoints.html), $X_{177}.$ See also [mid-arc triangle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Mid-ArcTriangle.html) for more information.

Comment: @timon92 How would one prove that $I_1,I_2,I_3 $lie on incirle of $ABC$ using $EI_1=I_1F $ etc.. ? Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @up I'm sorry I confused you. I meant: show that these points lie on the incircle and these equalities hold. 

You can show that the points lie on the incircle by showing that $\angle FI_1E = \frac \pi 2 + \frac{\angle BAC}$ and $\angle EDF = \frac \pi 2 - \frac{\angle BAC}2$.

Comment: @timon92 Bear with me ,but I wasn't able to do that .Can you post an answer to the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$\angle FI_1E = \pi - \angle I_1EF - \angle EFI_1 = \pi - \frac{\angle FEA}2 - \frac{\angle AEF}2 = \pi - \frac{\pi - \angle FAE}{2} = \frac{\pi + \angle BAC}{2}$$ and $$\angle EDF = \pi - \angle FDB - \angle CDE = \pi - \frac{\pi - \angle DBF}{2} - \frac{\pi - \angle ECD}{2} = \frac{\angle CBA}{2} + \frac{\angle ACB} 2 = \frac{\pi - \angle BAC}{2}.$$

Thus $\angle FI_1E + \angle EDF = \pi$ which means that $I_1$ lies on the circumcircle of $DEF$.

Observe now that $E$ and $F$ are symmetric with respect to a bisector of angle $BAC$ (which is $AI_1$). It follows that $I_1E=I_1F$ and so $DI_1$ is angle bisector of angle $FDE$.

We prove analogously that $EI_2$ and $FI_3$ are angle bisectors of angle $DEF$ and $EFD$, therefore these three lines pass through the incenter of $DEF$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.Somehow I lacked the intuition to see this simple method.Unfortunately I am not the OP otherwise I would have accepted your answer as soon as possible.+1