# Mistake in a proof concerning centers of incircles

Tags: geometry, proof-verification

[image]

In the above diagram we have that $D, E, F$ are the points of contact of the incircle of an acute-angled triangle $\Delta ABC$ with $BC, CA, AB$ respectively ,and  $I_1,I_2,I_3$ are the incentres of the triangles $AFE, BDF, CED $ respectively. How do I prove that the lines $I_1D,I_2E,I_3F$ are concurrent?

This question comes from [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1547512/geometry-question-on-incenters/1547837#1547837) ,which I've tried  to solve by showing that $OF=OI_1$ (I am trying to show that the center $I_1$ of the incircle of $\Delta AFE$ lies on the incircle of $\Delta ABC $).

For this I've tried to construct an indirect proof which starts by assuming that $OF=OY$ to show that this will imply some fact which must be true.However I had a contradiction in the end.

**Proof**

$OF=OI_1$

$OF^2=OI_1^2=OX\cdot AO=\cfrac{AI_1^2 \cdot OX}{AX}   \tag 1$

--->I've used the facts that $\Delta OFA$ is a right triangle( $O$ is the center of incircle of $\Delta ABC$ and $F$ is the point of tangency ) which implies $OF^2=OX\cdot AO$ ,and $FI$ is the angle bisector of $\Delta AFX$ which implies $\cfrac{OX}{AX}=\cfrac{OI_1^2}{AI_1^2}$

From $(1)$ I have
 $$AI_1^2=AO\cdot AX              \tag 2$$

Then we also get that $FX^2=OX \cdot AX=AX(AO-AX)=AX\cdot AO-AX^2$,which yields

$FX^2+AX^2=AX\cdot AO$

By $(2)$ we have that $AI_1^2=FX^2+AX^2=AF^2$ ,which implies $AI_1=AF$.

The last equality of course can't be true,so I 've made some mistake which I've tried hard to spot,however  I didn't find it.

Can you guys help ?

Edit:
I've obtained $(1)$ by the following:

(i) $OF^2=OX \cdot OA$

(ii) $AF^2=AO \cdot AX$

Using the fact that $FI_1$ is the angle bisector I have (iii) $\cfrac {OF}{AF}=\cfrac{OI_1}{AI_1}$

Rearranging (i),(ii) I have $\cfrac{OX}{AX}=\cfrac{OF^2}{AF^2}$

I also have by (iii) that $\cfrac{OI_1^2}{AI_1^2}=\cfrac{OF^2}{AF^2}$

Combining ratios I get:$\cfrac{OX}{AX}=\cfrac{OI_1^2}{AI_1^2}$

Comment: Hint: Once you prove that $I_1 D\perp I_2 I_3$, you have that $I_1 D, I_2 E$ and $I_3 F$ concur in the orthocentre of $I_1 I_2 I_3$. That is just a matter or angle chasing plus the fact that $II_1=II_2=II_3=r$ where $I$ is the incentre of $ABC$ and $r$ is the inradius.

Comment: I always take the peasant's way  to solve things,thank you @JackD'Aurizio.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in a mathematical approach, as soon as it works. You're welcome, by the way :)

Comment: Another interesting chance is given by the computation of the side lengths of the cyclic hexagon $I_1 E I_3 D I_2 F$ followed by an application of Brianchon's theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake starts in (1).

You wrote that $\frac{OX}{AX}=\frac{OI^2_1}{AI^2_1}$, which is incorrect.

**The proportion should've been** $\frac{OX}{AX}=\frac{OF^2}{AF^2}$.

I'm not really sure if this is the answer you want, but I will show by contradiction that the above is incorrect.

We have $\frac{OX}{AX}=\frac{OF^2}{AF^2}$, since $OF^2=OX \cdot OA$ and $AF^2=AX \cdot AO$.

The angle bisector theorem implies that $\frac{FA}{FX}=\frac{AI_1}{I_1X}$.

Assume, for the sake of contradiction, that $\frac{OX}{AX}=\frac{OI^2_1}{AI^2_1}$.

We now have $\frac{OF^2}{AF^2}=\frac{OX}{AX}=\frac{OI^2_1}{AI^2_1}$, so $\frac{OF^2}{OI^2_1}=\frac{FA^2}{AI^2_1}=\frac{FX^2}{I_1X^2}$.

Since you assumed that $OF=OI_1$, we have $FX=I_1X$, which is clearly impossible since $\angle I_1FX = \frac{1}{2} \angle AFX < \frac{1}{2} \angle AFO = 45$.

Comment: Can you show why it is incorrect ?That part  it's true because it comes from taking advantages of the proportions created by the altitude $FX$ in right triangle $AFO$.

Comment: Edited the solution.

Comment: I've edited so it's clear now where I got things from.

Comment: (iii) assumes that $FI_1$ is the angle bisector of $\angle AFO$. $FI_1$ is actually the angle bisector of $\angle AFX$.

Comment: Damn ,that's it.Thank you so much for your time !

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\triangle{OFA}$ and $\triangle{FXA}$ are similar, so we have
$$AO:AF=AF:AX,$$
i.e.$$AO\times AX=AF^2$$

Suppose that $(1)$ is true. Then, we have
$$AI_1=AF$$
This is impossible.

Comment: But why (1) isn't true ?I can't understand that.I've simply used proportions in a right triangle.